# Unable to start the daemon process. - Cordova

Tags: cordova, build, daemon

while using the following command

```
cordova build
```

its shows some errors

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

  Unable to start the daemon process.
  This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
  For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
  Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/
  2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

  ### Please read the following process output to find out more:

  Error occurred during initialization of VM
  Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove platform and add

Or
 check your jdk path in environment variables.
If same error occurs install new instance of jdk